# Generate WAR file using shell script

Tags: shell, jar, cron, war

The plan is to generate WAR files from the various files used in webapp so that it is easier to backup and restore. I use crontab and a shell script that runs every week. The script first uses jar -cvf to generate WAR file to a new location, then rsync happens to a NAS. This is what it roughly looks like:

```
now=$(date +%Y%m%d)    
jar -cvf /rsyncsource/$now.war /opt/webappfolder
rsync -rsvp --log-file=log.txt /rsyncsource/ /nas/
```

I tried running the script and it worked as expected: create WAR file and rsync to NAS. However, when I add the script to crontab for automation, no WAR file is generated and only rsync happens.

Would anyone care to enlighten a newbie? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be many reasons for the failure.

The environment variables of the cron daemon are not the same as the login shells.

In particular the **PATH** variable which is used to locate commands might not be the one you expect: the **jar** command would not be found in such situation, for example.

Could you provide all errors and output generated when the script was run by cron daemon?

---

## How to debug a script executed by the cron daemon?

At first, add **set -x** to the script in order to make bash generates trace messages:

```
$ cat /home/william/bin/script.sh
#!/bin/bash --
set -x
now=$(date +%Y%m%d)    
jar -cvf /rsyncsource/$now.war /opt/webappfolder
rsync -rsvp --log-file=log.txt /rsyncsource/ /nas/
```

### Solution 1

By default error output and standard output are all gathered and sent into an email to the current user mailbox.
All logins have their own local mailbox on linux and UNIX.
Connect as the user which own the crontab and type **mail**:

```
$ crontab -l
* * * * * /home/william/bin/script.sh
$ mail
```

The **mail** command offers a text interface and enables you to list and read emails received.
There is a help.

### Solution 2

Edit the crontab and redirect output to a file on the disk

```
$ crontab -l
* * * * * /home/william/bin/script.sh 2>/tmp/script.out >&2
```

Wait that cron daemon runs the script and debug with information logged into the /tmp/script.out file.

Comment: I used solution 2 to see the output of the script, and it said jar: command not found. It was indeed caused by different environment variable in crontab vs shell. Thanks a lot!